# Jquery mobile pagebeforehide Transition events not firing

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, jquery, transition

I am writing a simple alert that will trigger a pagebeforehide transition event, but it is not firing here is my code. NOTE: I am using Jquery-1.9.1.min.js" AND "jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.js"

```
  <script>
    $("section").live('pagebeforehide', function (event, ui) {
       alert("page being hidden" + ui.prevPage);
    });
  </script>
```

Here is the HTML

## Page Transition Example

This is page 1

Go to second page

```
<section id="secondpage" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Transition Example</h1>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content">
    <p>This is page 2</p>
    <a href="#firstpage">Go to first page</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there a change between versions of how to bind elements to the page transition events? Cause I can't get my code to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Live** is deprecated and don't exist any more in jQuery 1.9 +, you should use **on** instead.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ghAxp/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', 'section', function(event, ui){       
   alert("page being hidden");
});
```